# Union method for LinkedSet

Tags: java, set

I am trying to get the union of two LinkedSets of type T and do so as efficiently as I could. My approach was to make a new set (uSet) and addAll to that set for one LinkedSet and the other I would just use my add method as it shouldn't add any duplicates. However I am getting a "cannot find symbol" error while trying to use addAll. Here is what I have in the method at the moment.

```
   public Set<T> union(LinkedSet<T> s){
  
  if (s == null) {
     throw new NullPointerException();
  }
 
  LinkedSet<T> uSet = new LinkedSet<T>();
  uSet.addAll(s);
 
 
  
  return uSet;
```

}

I've been doing some googling and am way lost and feel like I'm in over my head here trying to understand what I'm doing so any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: LinkedSet is not a standard type.  Perhaps it doesn't define an addAll method?

Comment: Your method should also have a type parameter before the return type of the method. So something like `public <T> Set<T> union(LinkedHashSet<T> s)`

Comment: @Eritrean - he's supposedly using some LInkedSet, not LinkedHashSet.  (LInkedHashSet *has* an addAll method).   As to whether <T> is needed, it depends on whether the enclosing class is generic, with T as a type parameter there.

Comment: To the OP - where did this LinkedSet come from?  What is the import statement you used?